# Unable to unzip web2py_win.zip. WINZIP says it is an invalid zip format

Tags: web2py

WINZIP 12.0 and also WINRAR are both unable to open web2py_win.zip version 1.59
They both say the zip format is invalid.

Please advise what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: redownload it or write to the authors.

Answer (score 1):

[get 7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) it can handle anything. Tho I just downloaded web2py_win.zip from [here](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/download) and had no problem opening it as a compressed folder using plain ol XP. I think you should re-attempt your download / bet it got interrupted

Comment: Thanks. I have since found that I have a bad memory chip.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes notice a server drops a connection during a download or sends a wrong content-length header when downloading files and I get only parts of the file. So try to download again or download from another source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading via FTP, ensure that you do it in Binary mode, rather than Ascii...

Answer (score 0):

[Current version (1.66.2) seems to work](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_win.zip)